# Tablesorter disable pager button not working when using ajax

Tags: ajax, tablesorter, pager

The disable pager functionality is not working as I would expect when using ajax with tablesorter. The pager controls are disabled but the complete set of rows is not retrieved and shown. When not using ajax, it works fine - ie the complete set of rows is shown.

I notice that clicking on the disable pager button triggers the `showAllRows` function in the `jquery.tablesorter.pager` file. Then `showAllRows` calls `pagerArrows` if ajax is being used. This last function only seems to manipulate the css for the pager controls and does not re-render the table. Is this working properly for others?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does sound like a problem. I would recommend opening an [issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues?state=open) so that it can be tracked and addressed.

I am on a sabbatical at the moment, so if the caretakers of the repository are unable to take care of it, I will look into this issue upon my return. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Done - issue #353 opened. Enjoy your sabbatical and don't worry about the delay - the disable pager function is not critical for my implementation.